# array handling in python

Tags: python, arrays, self

i am just trying...but the self.value show error ie...i want to loop self.a,self.b,self.c...help require for learning help required......output wanted is x= [AA,EE,II] using classes and loops.i tried looping the self.a,self.b,self.c using for loop.........i am learning python and object oriented programming newly....help me out

```
import string
A = ["AA","BB","CC","DD"]
B = ["EE","FF","GG","HH"]
C = ["II","JJ","KK","LL"]
class User:
    def __init__(self,A,B,C):
        self.a= A
        self.b= B
        self.c= C

    def User1(self):
        x=[]
        for i in range(ord('a'), ord('c')+1):
            value= chr(i)
            x.append= self.(value)[0] ///for getting first elemen from A,B,C
            i+=1
        return x


honey= User(A,B,C)
print(honey.User1())
```

Comment: `x.append= self.(value)[0]` doesn't make any sense. To append to a list, you would use `x.append(value[0])`. You can't use `self.value` here because it's not an instance attribute (or define it as `self.value= chr(i)` beforehand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHat you want is to use `getattr` - but there are a few other things broken there. (to start with the fact that the comment character is `#` in Python, and not the `//` sequence.

So, your User1 method could be something like:

```
   def User1(self):
        x=[]
        for value in "abc":
            x.append(getattr(self, value)[0])
        return x
```

Note as well that the `for` statement will always iterate over a sequence, and you don't need to go long ways to convert your sequence to numbers, just for converting those numbers back to the desired elements. As a string is also a sequence of characters - just looping over "abc" will yield your desired letters.

As stated above, the `getattr` built-in will then retrieve the desired attribute from `self` gven the attribute name as a string, contained in the `value` variable.

Comment: @roganjosh: I just kept it  hardcoded it to go "easy" with the minimum needed modifications for the OP to understand what is going on.  
I agree that iterating over `self.__dict__` can be more generic - but it would have to be explained throughfully  to do more good than harm. And, if you think on going down that way, maybe it would be better to talk about the Sequence protocol at once, and have te OP implement `__iter__`  at once.